# SOAP Attachments using apache axis2

Tags: java, apache, soap, apache-axis, attachment

Does anyone know a good beginner's tutorial on how to send attachments with SOAP messages using axis2. Every tutorial I have found so far has been very difficult to follow. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few months ago I've read the book "Developing Web Services with Apache Axis2" by Mr. *Kent Ka Iok Tong*. I think this is an excellent book for beginners, example driven and easy to understand. It contains plenty of code/xml snippets and has a chapter devoted to your question.

Perhaps there is one problem. The book is very easy to follow but you should read it cover-to-cover to grasp everything. Nevertheless I recommend it as an excellent book for Axis2 novices. Please note that neither this book is a complete Axis2 reference nor it provides in-depth knowledge of Axis2. This is a book for new users.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much @lucho I will buy the book and read the book and give you feedback.

Comment: I came here for the title of the question. And that one is not covered in the response at all unfortunately.