# How to generate non-secure stubs in Axis2 using wsdl2java

Tags: apache-axis

I am attempting to learn Axis2 Web Services, and am working through a tutorial on RoseIndia web site ([link text](http://www.roseindia.net/webservices/axis2/index.shtml)).  In the example for the client, it generates the stubs using wsdl2java, and it generates the stubs which use http://localhost:8080, however, when I do it, it creates the stubs to use the secure links https://localhost:8443.  I have not installed SSL onto my local dev app server (Tomcat).

I have checked the wsdl2java documentation and can't find any reference to security settings.  How would I make these stubs use the basic http://localhost:8080 references

Comment: The RoseIndia stuff is pretty bad, I'd advise finding a different source for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your WSDL file. In Axis2 1.5 the `wsdl2java` tool will use this SOAP1.2 port to generate the target endpoint for your stub:

```
<wsdl:port name="HelloWorldServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:HelloWorldServiceSoap12Binding">
  <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8082/axis2/services/HelloWorldService.HelloWorldServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint/" />
</wsdl:port>
```

You can use the `-pn` option of `wsdl2java` if you need to use another port.

Download your WSDL locally and verify that the port section is correct (no https). Further generate the sources with wsdl2java, e.g. on my machine:

```
lucho@lucholinuxpc:~/axis2-1.5.1/bin> ./wsdl2java.sh -uri /home/lucho/sayhello.wsdl
 Using AXIS2_HOME:   /home/lucho/axis2-1.5.1
 Using JAVA_HOME:       /opt/jdk1.6.0_18
 Using JAVA_OPTS:    -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
Retrieving document at '/home/lucho/sayhello.wsdl'.
```

Now check your generated stub, you should see something like this in case your WSDL looks like mine:

```
/**
 * Default Constructor
 */
public HelloWorldServiceStub() throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {
        this("http://localhost:8082/axis2/services/HelloWorldService.HelloWorldServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint/" );
}
```

Next, in your test code you may alternatively use a constructor for your stub that takes the target endpoint. Actually I prefer this approach because the WS client is more flexible to changes in the target network. For your question should be something like:

```
public HelloWorldServiceStub(java.lang.String targetEndpoint)
```

And last but not least I recommend you this book for quick start-up tutorial [SOAP Attachments using apache axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392002/soap-attachments-using-apache-axis2/4392119#4392119)

Cheerz!